# Laravel paginator, custom page number value

Tags: laravel, paginator

Trying to create custom pagination on Laravel,

I am tring to paginate a collection build with values from two entities (users, organisations)

Is there any way to change the page number value to a custom value ?

Or can i append  custom query string and value to each page url ?

Comment: Hi, you can read this article on Laravel official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#cursor-pagination

Comment: @64Bit1990 yes i have read, i do not paginate a resource, i paginate an collection built doing some database queries. That why i need the above.

Answer (score 0):

you can use skip() and take() for custom pagination.

skip() will work as offset and take() will work as a limit.

ex.  page = 0;  offset = 0; limit = 10;

offset = page * limit;

limit = 10;

query->skip(offset)->take(limit)->get();

You can pass the values of page number & limit to your query.

Value of limit should be greater than 0

Hope this will work for you.